# Is Entropy of a Discrete Random Variable Condition on a Continuous Random Variable Always bigger than or Equal to Zero?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable and $Y$ be a continuous random variable. Is the conditional entropy of $X$ given $Y$ always positive, i.e., $H(X|Y)\ge0$?

Comment: of course...........

Comment: How can you prove it?@Andrew

Comment: Do you know how to prove entropy is nonnegative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of trivial. If you know that the Shannon entropy of a discrete variable is non-negative, and you accept the natural extension of the definition of (discrete) conditional entropy, when the conditioning variable is continuous with a density function, you'd write

$$H(X|Y) = \int f_Y(y) H(X|Y=y) \, dy$$

Now, $H(X|Y=y) \ge 0 $ because that's the entropy of a discrete variable (with pmf $P(X|Y=y)$). Then $H(X|Y) \ge 0$.